# How does one put an article's publication day and month into a .bib file when using biber and biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I've been using BibTeX for a while and am slowly making the transition to biber and the biblatex package. For years, I've been told that the correct way to indicate that a paper was published on, say, April 1st, is to put an entry in the `.bib` file that looks like this:

```
    month=Apr # " 1"
```

The reason is that the `Apr` is a built-in `@string` expansion that is localized to April in the current language, the `#` is a BibTex language thing for 'concatenate,' and that most bib styles have no provisions for day-of-the-month.

I've been doing this with biber and getting messages that look like this:

```
WARN - month field 'June 6' in entry 'haber-smithsonian' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Here is how I bring biblatex in:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=american]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

And here is how I print it:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Bibliography %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{}
\renewcommand{\shortchaptertitle}{Bibliography}
\fancyhead[C]{\emph{\shortchaptertitle}}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

So what is the right way to indicate in the `.bib` file that something was published on April 1st?

Comment: For the month, it should be  `month={6}`.

Comment: Note that in most cases the `biblatex` option `language=american` is not necessary and that it often does not do what people think it does. `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` after `\printbibliography` may send the wrong page number to the ToC in case of multi-page bibliographies. Use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` instead. Indeed you could probably define a new bibliography heading that already includes all the page setup you do before `\printbibliography`, that would give a slightly less cluttered document body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [pst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48251/pst)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557277/35864) the best way to give a full date with day precision in `biblatex` is via the `date` field. `biblatex`'s `...date` fields support ISO 8601 input, so you would say `date = {YYYY-MM-DD},`, e.g.

```
date = {1980-04-01},
```

`year` and `month` are really only supported for backwards compatibility with (standard) BibTeX styles. (Note that `month` and `year` are only supported for the standard `date` field: Other date fields like `urldate`, `eventdate`, ... must not be given in date parts. So `urlyear` would not be correct input - if it works that is only accidental and nothing you can or should rely on.)

If you don't want to or cannot modify your `.bib` file to properly make use of `date`, here is a (slightly convoluted) Biber sourcemap that automatically maps month-day-constructions in the `month` field to a proper `date` field.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{(\d)\s+(\d)}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, fieldvalue={-0$1-0$2}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{(\d{2})\s+(\d)}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, fieldvalue={-$1-0$2}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{(\d)\s+(\d{2})}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, fieldvalue={-0$1-$2}, append]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=regexpeddate, fieldvalue={-$1-$2}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=regexpeddate, final]
      \step[fieldset=date, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldset=year, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  month   = Apr # " 1",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1st Apr. 1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service.]

Comment: This is great. I guess I need to read the 150 page manual. How do I enter just a year and a month? Use just year= and month=?

Comment: @vy32 Either that (`year = {2020}, month = jul,`/`year = {2020}, month = {7},`) or use `date`: `date = {2020-07},`. The date fields support ISO 8601 input, so you can do all sorts `date = {2020-07/2020-08-09},`

Answer (score 1):

Since you know about and use `month` field it seems easiest to find this out looking up that field in [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). There it says

> **month** field (literal)
>
> The publication month. This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a string. Don’t say month={January} but
> month={1}. The bibliography style converts this to a language
> dependent string or ordinal where required. This field is a literal
> field only when given explicitly in the data (for plain BibTeX
> compatibility for example). It is however better to use the date field
> as this supports many more features. See §§ 2.3.8 and 2.3.9.

So follow that advice, using the `date` field to state the whole date instead.